# Set value of WTForms field to an elements css style

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I want to insert a HiddenField into a looping html form, and define the value of this hidden field to be the css color of a related clickable div element. This means that if a user clicks the div until its red, then submits their form, I should receive back the css background style of `#FF0000` as the value of the HiddenField.

Heres the clickable div and function I'm using for input:

```
<div class="cell">
    <div style="background: #00cc00;" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
</div>

    var backgrounds = ["#ffbf00", "#FF0000", "#00cc00"];
    function setColor(el) {
        el.colorIdx = el.colorIdx || 0;
        el.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[el.colorIdx++ % backgrounds.length];
    }
```

and heres my hidden field:

```
{{ form.chosen_colour }}
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Yes it's probably achievable.  Can you explain which part you need help with, or what's currently not working for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what approach will work. Can I include a javascript function in a jinja2 variable, and then try and extract the value back to Flask using that? e.g. `{{ form.chosen_colour(value=myJavascriptFunction()) }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved this by replacing the hidden field with a hidden input, and linking it to the JavaScript as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_{{ user.user_id }}" id="user_{{ blogpost.blogpost_id }}">

 var backgrounds = ["#ffbf00", "#FF0000", "#00cc00"];
    function setColor(el, state_id) {
        el.colorIdx = el.colorIdx || 0;
        el.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[el.colorIdx++ % backgrounds.length];
        var hidden_color = document.getElementById('user_' + blogpost_id);
        hidden_color.value = el.style.backgroundColor
    }
```

I also used the following to access the hidden input value in the Flask backend:

```
value = request.form['user_14']
```